# Installation error on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation, ubuntu-11.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and now, when I try to install or uninstall a software, I get this error

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ...  (Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ... 10% (Reading database ... 15% (Reading database ... 20% (Reading database ... 25% (Reading database ... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading database ... 40% (Reading database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50% (Reading database ... 55% (Reading database ... 60% (Reading database ... 65% (Reading database ... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading database ... 80% (Reading database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90% (Reading database ... 95% (Reading database ... 100% (Reading database ... 158945 files and directories currently installed.) 
Removing aisleriot ... 
Processing triggers for gconf2 ... 
Processing triggers for man-db ... 
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ... 
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ... 
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ... 
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ... 
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ... 
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index... 
Setting up flashplugin-downloader (11.0.1.152ubuntu1) ... 
Downloading... 
--2012-05-02 18:47:29--  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.0.1.152.orig.tar.gz 
Resolving archive.canonical.com... 91.189.92.150, 91.189.92.191 
Connecting to archive.canonical.com|91.189.92.150|:80... connected. 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 
2012-05-02 18:47:29 ERROR 404: Not Found. 

download failed 
The Flash plugin is NOT installed. 
dpkg: error processing flashplugin-downloader (--configure): 
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer: 
 flashplugin-installer depends on flashplugin-downloader (>= 11.0.1.152ubuntu1); however: 
  Package flashplugin-downloader is not configured yet. 
dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure): 
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 flashplugin-downloader 
 flashplugin-installer 
Error in function:  
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) 
Setting up flashplugin-downloader (11.0.1.152ubuntu1) ... 
Downloading... 
--2012-05-02 18:47:33--  http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.0.1.152.orig.tar.gz 
Resolving archive.canonical.com... 91.189.92.191, 91.189.92.150 
Connecting to archive.canonical.com|91.189.92.191|:80... connected. 
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 
2012-05-02 18:47:34 ERROR 404: Not Found. 

download failed 
The Flash plugin is NOT installed. 
dpkg: error processing flashplugin-downloader (--configure): 
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer: 
 flashplugin-installer depends on flashplugin-downloader (>= 11.0.1.152ubuntu1); however: 
  Package flashplugin-downloader is not configured yet. 
dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure): 
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

This seems to be a bug that has been reported.Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Get rid of the package and manually install the flash plugin?  Don't use flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean install of Ubuntu solved this!